# Reading CSV file into excel using VBA then outputting the results to a specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I've been searching for a while and can't find a simple solution. I've got a csv file that I would like to read into excel using vba and output the results into a specific cell range on a specific worksheet.

I've been using the following code, but if I run the excel macro twice it basically appends the data on the next blank column instead of copying over it. It also only pastes it into the active sheet instead of my specific sheet.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Thanks,

```
Public Sub Example()
    Const csPath As String = "starting_positions.csv"
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet
    With ws.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & csPath, ws.Cells(1, 1))
        .FieldNames = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        ''// This array will need as many entries as there will be columns:
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(xlTextFormat, xlTextFormat)
        .Refresh
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you run the code in the same workbook you need to collect CSV data to, try the following:

1. Replace `Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet` with `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` or `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` to define any specific sheet using either its index or name.
2. `ws.UsedRange.ClearContents` place **prior** `With...` block will clear the whole sheet, and therefore new data will be placed to the same place as before.

One more hint: in case you're going to use this macro **many times** - do not create every time a new connection. In case all the options are similar - only use `.Refresh` method.

If you're stuck with the merging of code parts - try to use macro recorder passing any of the steps manually. For your case this will solve the majority of troubles. Good luck!

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually a follow up. I'm only going to be using this once when I open the excel sheet. Should I be worried about closing the connection? or is it fine as is?

Comment: @user1898958 I think such "connections" are fine to leave as it is - I use such one-time solutions frequently and don't even think about it. However, if you're pretty sure this is "launch and forget" solution - add the following lines of code: `.Name = "Conn_Name"` - anywhere in the connection setup options block, and `ThisWorkbook.Connections("Conn_Name").Delete` after `End With`. This will add connection, retry data, and delete it thereafter.